# Is $Φ^T$ a linear operator which transforms simultaneous equations such that we obtain LMS solution?

Tags: regression, modeling, linear-model, least-squares, linear-algebra

If we have $\vec e(w) = \vec t-\Phi \vec w$ and we wish to minimize $\vec e(w)^T \vec e(w) $ w.r.t $\vec w$,

This is same as wanting the best fit solution to the the set of $n$ simultaneous equations with $p$ parameters i.e $\vec t-\Phi \vec w = \vec 0 $,

Which can be written as

$\Large \Phi \vec w=\vec t - (1)$

Now note that if we apply the linear operator $\Phi^T$ to the above equation, 
$\Phi^T (\Phi w) = \Phi^T (t)$

We obtain a **new** set of simultaneous equations

$\Large (\Phi^T \Phi) w = \Phi^T t - (2)$

This new set of equations have $p$ equations and the same $p$ parameters, thus as long as this square matrix $(\Phi^T \Phi)$ is invertible we can directly solve for the parameter vector.

1) The matrix $\Phi^T $ maps ($\Phi w)_{n \times 1}$ in $R^n $ to $((\Phi^T \Phi) w)_{n \times 1}$ in $R^p$.
But is it also right to say the matrices themselves are changed? That is $\Phi^T$ transforms the coefficients of the old set of equations (1) into the coefficients of the new set of equations (2).

2) While this operator makes the equations solvable, I don't get how the solution to these new set of $p$ equations (2) just happens to be **identical** to the Least MSE solution of those $n$ equations (1).Is there any particular reason why this happens?

Thanks @whuber for suggestions.

Comment: Skip the first page, which is standard material that has appeared hundreds of times on this site.  State your question at the outset.  Use the MathJax markup to provide more consistent typesetting of formulas.  If you think lots of background material is necessary, *still* ask your question at the outset and then follow it with the details.  That's what "tl;dr" is for!

Comment: How does it look now? Should I add the background material at the bottom?

Comment: It's more readable, but I cannot make sense of it.  At the very beginning you ask something meaningless: one cannot "minimize" a vector!  The subsequent manipulations appear to have nothing to do with that situation, anyway.  It looks like you are just reproducing some of the algebra used in ordinary least squares and then you wind up asking how you managed to get the OLS solution.

Comment: Sorry yeah you can't minimize a vector, I corrected that. After that I am just showing how the best fit solutions of (1) turn out to be the actual solutions of (2).

Comment: OK.  However, that doesn't seem to change anything: you write down the normal equations for OLS regression and then you ask how the solutions happen to be identical to OLS solutions.  Your question seems circular and without any content.

Comment: The ols solution was obtained by differentiating the MSE wrt w and then equating to 0, by that method we get the value of w. But I then noticed that if we rewrite the solution, we can think of it as the set of equations having been transformed by $\Phi^T$, so this seemed to be a different way of arriving at this same solution. I wondered if was any reason this happens, it could also be that its just a some mathematical manipulation of the solution which has no separate meaning from the original solution - when you differentiate and equate to 0.